# Tesseract use subset of letters

Tags: python, linux, ocr, captcha, tesseract

Im using tesseract-ocr package on Ubuntu Linux, I have been using it for a while and I think that in order to improve the accuracy of the OCR I only need a subset of letters from the alphabet. The letters I need are:

```
0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

and only that, not even capital letters, can anybody give me a hand on indicating tesseract to only match againts a subset of letters ?

Thanks,

Comment: I am trying to understand for what valid reasons you would want to decode captcha.

Comment: @Andrey it's a fun challenge problem, for one :)

Comment: @Nisan.H one and the only. Phrase "using it for a while" get me cautious.

Comment: "using it for a while" I ment playing around with tesseract on a set of images that I have.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [python-tesseract project page](https://code.google.com/p/python-tesseract/):

```
import tesseract
api = tesseract.TessBaseAPI()
api.Init(".","eng",tesseract.OEM_DEFAULT)
api.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
api.SetPageSegMode(tesseract.PSM_AUTO)
```

So just set your own collection of characters in `api.SetVariable`.

From the [tesseract-ocr project FAQ](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/FAQ#How_do_I_recognize_only_digits?)

> **Tesseract 2.03**
>   Use

```
TessBaseAPI::SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789");
```

> BEFORE calling an Init function or put this in a text file called
>   tessdata/configs/digits:

```
tessedit_char_whitelist 0123456789
```

> and then your command line becomes:

```
tesseract image.tif outputbase nobatch digits
```

> **Warning**: Until the old
>   and new config variables get merged, you must have the nobatch
>   parameter too.
>
> **Tesseract 3**
>   A digits config file is already created, so just run a
>   tesseract command like this:

```
tesseract imagename outputbase digits
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the Tesseract Whitelist. If you're on python and working with it and the API, I think this should work (found on the Tesseract Google Group).

```
api.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789 ");
```

Note, I'm not sure which version of Tesseract this is for.