# No module named tesseract

Tags: python, python-2.7, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

Working on an OCR. I can import pytesseract and use image_to_string but I want to work on this:

```
api = tesseract.TessBaseAPI()
api.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789")
api.Init('.','eng',tesseract.OEM_DEFAULT)
api.SetPageSegMode(tesseract.PSM_AUTO)
```

This is to set tesseract to detect only numbers or alphabets.
When I run my code I get this error:

`ImportError: No module named tesseract`

I have tesseract-ocr installed, and pytesseract as well. Yet I keep getting this error.

Comment: I'm not the big python guy but i think this is the 5th time this month i read about this Error on SO. Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33401767/importerror-no-module-named-pytesseract

Comment: I guess he's already done with, pip install pytesseract

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15512193/tesseract-use-subset-of-letters

Comment: I think this will help!

Comment: @U.Swap thats exactly what I'm aiming for but I get the no module named tessseract error. despite pip installing pytesseract and tesseract-ocr

Comment: Have you solved the problem? If not, can you edit the question to include your complete code for looking at it?

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this problem while trying to run pytesseract in Pycharm. Make sure you have an environmental path var to the Tesseract folder. This way the program knows to use the tesseract.exe from the installed location.

This is what my path looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can install tesseract by using below command

```
pip install tesseract
```

Comment: It installs tesseract-0.1.3. But when I try to import tesseract it shows this error: SyntaxError: invalid syntax