# I am having an issue with my Raspberry Pi when using pytesseract

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have installed it properly with this tutorial: "https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/optical-character-recognition-ocr-using-tesseract-on-raspberry-pi". When I write in the command line `tesseract image.png stdout` it works. But when running the following script:

```
 import pytesseract 
 from PIL import Image 

 image=Image.open('image.png')
 text=pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config='') 
 print(text)
```

It replies:

```
Error on line 1
ImportError: No module named tesseract
```

Comment: Did you do `pip install pytesseract`? Are you using the default python2.7 interpreter or the python3 one?

Comment: Yes, I did pip install pytesseract and I'm using the default python 2.7.

Comment: Have you already looked at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42369652/no-module-named-tesseract

Comment: I would look at this perhaps when it was installed it defaulted to your python3 path try it with python3 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33401767/importerror-no-module-named-pytesseract

Answer (score 0):

you have to do that: `pip install pytesseract`, if the problem persists try this (only if you use Windows), add the environmental path var to the Tesseract folder like this [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRaI6.png), you have also to change the var on line 5 img -> image